# How to get number of rows affected in mysql in each update queries

Tags: mysql

Is there any possibilities is there for capture number of rows affected in each update query which logging into binlog of mysql. Any guys please share

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an awk script that will use the mysqlbinlog output and print a beautiful summary for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE events from row-based binary logs. 
Just replace the `mysqld-bin.000023` with your binary log file also `--start-datetime="2015-01-12 21:40:00"` and `--stop-datetime="2015-01-12 21:45:00"` with values you prefer. [Source](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/20/identifying-useful-information-mysql-row-based-binary-logs/)

```
mysqlbinlog --base64-output=decode-rows -vv --start-datetime="2015-01-12 21:40:00"  --stop-datetime="2015-01-12 21:45:00" mysqld-bin.000023 | awk \
'BEGIN {s_type=""; s_count=0;count=0;insert_count=0;update_count=0;delete_count=0;flag=0;} \
{if(match($0, /#15.*Table_map:.*mapped to number/)) {printf "Timestamp : " $1 " " $2 " Table : " $(NF-4); flag=1} \
else if (match($0, /(### INSERT INTO .*..*)/)) {count=count+1;insert_count=insert_count+1;s_type="INSERT"; s_count=s_count+1;}  \
else if (match($0, /(### UPDATE .*..*)/)) {count=count+1;update_count=update_count+1;s_type="UPDATE"; s_count=s_count+1;} \
else if (match($0, /(### DELETE FROM .*..*)/)) {count=count+1;delete_count=delete_count+1;s_type="DELETE"; s_count=s_count+1;}  \
else if (match($0, /^(# at) /) && flag==1 && s_count>0) {print " Query Type : "s_type " " s_count " row(s) affected" ;s_type=""; s_count=0; }  \
else if (match($0, /^(COMMIT)/)) {print "[Transaction total : " count " Insert(s) : " insert_count " Update(s) : " update_count " Delete(s) : " \
delete_count "] \n+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+"; \
count=0;insert_count=0;update_count=0; delete_count=0;s_type=""; s_count=0; flag=0} } '
```

Sample output

```
Timestamp : #150112 21:40:14 Table : `test`.`t` Query Type : INSERT 1 row(s) affected
Timestamp : #150112 21:40:14 Table : `test`.`t` Query Type : UPDATE 1 row(s) affected
Timestamp : #150112 21:40:14 Table : `test`.`t` Query Type : DELETE 1 row(s) affected
[Transaction total : 3 Insert(s) : 1 Update(s) : 1 Delete(s) : 1] 
+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Select Row_Count();
```